# How to give different background colors to each grid view item?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a GridView as my MainActivity consisting of 11 items with Clickable Listener. Each cell conists of an ImageView and TextView .I want to give each of the 11 items diffrent Background color.

This is my items Array

```
public static String [] prgmNameList={"TownHall 1","TownHall 2",
            "TownHall 3","TownHall 4","TownHall 5 ","TownHall 6",
            "TownHall 7","TownHall 8","TownHall 9","TownHall 10","TownHall 11"};
    public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.town_hall1,
            R.drawable.town_hall2,R.drawable.town_hall3,
            R.drawable.town_hall4,R.drawable.town_hall5,
            R.drawable.town_hall6,R.drawable.town_hall7,
            R.drawable.town_hall8,R.drawable.town_hall9,
    R.drawable.town_hall10, R.drawable.town_hall11};
```

This is my code to GridView Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapterMainActivity extends BaseAdapter {

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapterMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        ImageView img;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_item_gridview, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);



        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Class<? extends Activity> activityToStart = null;
                switch (position) {

                    case 0:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        activityToStart = TownHallNineActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 9:
                        activityToStart = TownHallTenActivity.class;
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        activityToStart = TownHallElevenActivity.class;

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }
                Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), activityToStart);
                i.putExtra("classFrom", activityToStart.toString());
               context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code it works just fine !

1) Your class supposing category class:

```
 public class Category extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

CategoryAdapter catAdpater;
FragmentController controller;
FragmentCommunicator communicator;

ArrayList<Integer> catImages = new ArrayList<>();
GridView catGrid;
String[] gridItem = {
        "Technology",
        "Food & Drink",
        "Catering",
        "Education",
        "Travel",
        "Accessories",
        "Cleaners",
        "Cloth",
        "Random"
};

String[] gridColor = {
        "#3c6169",
        "#30515d",
        "#284b5e",
        "#224156",
        "#86a6a1",
        "#729493",
        "#3c6169",
        "#30515d",
        "#224156",
        "#3c6169"
};


LinearLayout categoryLayout;
ImageView back;


public Category() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
    //controller = new FragmentController();
    //communicator = (FragmentCommunicator)getActivity();



    //MrVector.inflate(getResources(), R.drawable.phone);
    catGrid = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.catGrid);
    categoryLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.header);
    back =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.back);
    categoryLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //empty
        }
    });
    back.setOnClickListener(this);

    ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add("Technology");
    categories.add("Food & Drink");
    categories.add("Catering");
    categories.add("Education");
    categories.add("Travel");
    categories.add("Accessories");
    categories.add("Cleaners");
    categories.add("Cloth");
    categories.add("Random");


    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_phone_iphone_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_local_drink_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_school_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_airplanemode_active_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_watch_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_phone_iphone_white_48dp);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_action_accessibility);
    catImages.add(R.drawable.ic_store_mall_directory_white_48dp);

    catAdpater = new CategoryAdapter(this.getContext(),categories,catImages,gridColor);
    catGrid.setAdapter(catAdpater); }
```

2) Your custom adapter:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> cat_name;
ArrayList<Integer> images;
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final String[] gridcolor;

public CategoryAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> cat_name, ArrayList<Integer> images,String[] gridcolor)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.cat_name = cat_name;
    this.gridcolor = gridcolor;
    this.images = images;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    CategoryHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);
        holder = new CategoryHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (CategoryHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    try {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(images.get(position))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .error(R.drawable.nopicture)
                .into(holder.image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MYDEBUG3", e.getMessage());
    }
    holder.name.setText(cat_name.get(position));
    holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(gridcolor[position]));
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your getView():

```
rowView.setBackgroundColor(colors[position]));
```

And add an array of colors like this:

```
public static int [] colors { 0x225522, 0xff00000, .... }
```